# How to Drag and Drop multiple files between Namespace extensions

Tags: visual-c++, com

I am working on a namespace extension project, I need to implement multiple files drag and drop between Namespace Extensions. I have used  DragQueryFile API to find the the number of files. But Always this Function give a crash.

Could anyone help me by explaining how we can implement this multiple files Drag and drop.

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: `DragQueryFile` only works with the data format `CF_HDROP` which only supports files/paths with a text representation (e.g. real filesystem files). If you're writing your own namespace extension you probably need to use native COM drag/drop (`DoDragDrop`, `IDataObject`, `IDropSource`, `IDropTarget`, etc).

Comment: Hi Jonathan,thanks for the update. I am using COM Drag and drop only in the project. But I need to drag and drop files between extension. I am able to implement drag and drop for one file if multiple files are selected. Now I want to iterate through the PIDL data and find other elements.could you please provide some light regarding how to iterate through the pidl and find the next items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use it

```
void yourclass::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{


    TCHAR lpszFile[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    UINT uFile = 0;

    uFile = DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, NULL);
    if (uFile != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < uFile; i++)
        {
            lpszFile[0] = '\0';
            if (DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, i, lpszFile, MAX_PATH))
            {
                std::wstring directory;
                std::wstring filename;
                LVITEM lvi = { 0 };
                lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_PARAM;

                SplitPath(lpszFile, directory, filename);

                lvi.iSubItem = 0;
                lvi.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;
                lvi.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;

                int n = m_wndFileList.InsertItem(&lvi);
                m_wndFileList.SetItemText(n, 0, filename.c_str());
                m_wndFileList.SetItemText(n, 1, directory.c_str());

            }
        }
    }
    DragFinish(hDropInfo);
    return;
    CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);
}
```